# mongodb data updated, but axios is fetching old data

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, redux

When a user updates his profile in editProfile component,the data is updated in the server and the user is redirected to the userProfile component. Now in the userProfile, users data is fetched from the server. Here i am getting the old data. But if i refresh the page, i get the updated data.

//api

```
router.post('/:uid/edit', (req, res) => {
const updatedUser = {
    name : req.body.name,
    avatar : req.body.avatar,
    bio : req.body.bio
};
 console.log('updateduser',updatedUser);
 User.findOneAndUpdate({uid: req.params.uid}, {$set: updatedUser}, 
 {"new":true})
     .then(user => {
         res.json(user);
         console.log(user);
        })
     .catch(err => {
         console.log('er',err);
     });
});
```

//action

```
 export const usersFetchData = (url) => {
 return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(userIsLoading(true));
    axios
        .get(url)
        .then(res => {
            if(!res){
                throw Error(res.statusText)
            }
            dispatch(userIsLoading(false));
            console.log(res.data); //getting old data 
            return res.data;    
        })
        .then(users => {
            console.log('users',users);
            dispatch(usersFetchDataSuccess(users))
        })
        .catch(() => dispatch(userHasErrored(true)));
}
}
```

Comment: Are you shore cache is not your problem?

Comment: I am not using any cache

Answer (score 2):

Most likely this is due to `axios` caching. See what you have in the axios settings and if

```
'Cache-Control': 'no-cache'
```

is set. Usually via:

```
var config = {headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json','Cache-Control' : 'no-cache'}};

axios.get('/get', config)  // <-- config
```

If this does not work you can always just append a timestamp to the request to make sure it always makes a request.

Comment: got the below error   :   Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:5000/api/user/GHfd4UbusVUV5Ofo3xU4gH3XDFv2' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field Cache-Control is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

Comment: Ok. Try adding a time stamp then as suggested

Comment: axios.get(`${url}?timestamp=${new Date().getTime()}`)  - is this the right way to add a timestamp? Do i need to make any change in the express api endpoint?

Comment: That seems like it should work. Sorry on mobile at the moment

Comment: now its again fetcing old data. i don't know what the hell is happening

Comment: Hi, may I know how you solved this? was facing the same issue